# Update a given table with a filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, html

I have a table which I want to re-sort by picking a tab or menu item.

Context:
The table is populated with all "orders" in the SQL DB, and by clicking a tab for a specific area it should update the table with orders only in that area.

Can I make an IF statement somehow, or a while-loop in angular?

Currently it gets its data like this in php (where I already try to filter);

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode($data);

// creates a connection to the mysql server
require('connection.php');

$filterGeo = $filterSta = $filterNH = $filterNot = '%';

if (isset($_GET['filterGeo'])) {$filterGeo = $_GET['filterGeo'];};
if (isset($_GET['filterSta'])) {$filterSta = $_GET['filterSta'];};
if (isset($_GET['filterNH'])) {$filterNH = $_GET['filterNH'];};
if (isset($_GET['filterNot'])) {$filterNot = $_GET['filterNot'];};


$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM orders
    Where address LIKE '%$filterGeo%' AND status LIKE '%$filterSta%'");

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"orderID":"'  . $rs["orderID"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"customerID":"'  . $rs["customerID"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"date":"'   . $rs["date"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"address":"'. $rs["address"]  . '",';
    $outp .= '"area":"'. $rs["area"]     . '"}';
}

$outp ='{"orders":['.$outp.']}';
$outp = utf8_encode($outp);

$conn->close();
echo($outp);

//?>
```

And the JSON is handled by angular like this;

```
var app = angular.module('Orders', []);   app.controller('getOrders', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get("/filterOrders.php")
     .then(function (response) {$scope.orders = response.data.orders;});   });
```

The relevant HTML snippet:

```
  <div ng-app="Orders" ng-controller="getOrders">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Alle</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Odder</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Hørning</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Ry</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Skanderborg</a></li>
            </ul>
          <table class="table table-condensed table-border table-striped">
            <thead align="center">
              <th>Order #</th>
              <th>Customer #</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Area</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>OrderType</th>
              <th>TrashcanType</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>RenoNord Invoice</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in orders">
                <td>{{ x.orderID }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.customerID }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.address }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.area }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.orderType }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.trashcanType }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.status }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.renonord }}</td>

                <td class="text-right">
                  <button href="#" data-id="{{ x.orderID }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Ret</button>
                  <button href="#" data-id="{{ x.orderID }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Slet</button>
                </td>
```

Comment: Can you add the html part as well?

Comment: So what I understand is, you get all the data now without filtering once when the controller starts, and when you click on any of the `li` elements you would like to add a filter accordingly, right?

Comment: Yep exactly, and update the table with that filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you want to filter the result set (client or server side), you got a couple of options:

**Filtering client side:**

Add `ng-click` directive to your options. With that you can set a scope variable which you would use to filter by.

```
<li role="presentation"><a ng-click="areaFilter = 'Odder'">Odder</a></li>
```

Filtering the results with `filter` in ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in orders | filter: {area: areaFilter}">
```

**Filtering server side:**

In this case you will have to make a new request to the server every time you apply a new filter. The semantics are the same, but in this case you'll call a function on `ng-click` instead of assigning a string to a variable.

```
<li role="presentation"><a ng-click="filter('Odder')">Odder</a></li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.filter = function(val) {
    // create the url you want to call depending on "val"
    var url = '/filterOrders.php';
    switch (val) {
        case 'Odder':
            url += '?filterXY=Odder';
            break;
        default: break;
    }
    $http.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.orders = response.data.orders;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use angular filters:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in orders | filter:{area:'MyArea'}">
```

`...`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to filter a table in angular. On your tabs, have it set a variable when it's clicked:

```
<li role="presentation"><a data-ng-click="areaFilter = 'Odder'">Odder</a></li>
```

Then use the filter in your ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in orders | filter: {area: areaFilter}">
```

Just make sure that you set `areaFilter = ''` in your controller, and your All tab should use that same assignment.